# TypeScript reports property is missing from instance of class that I'm trying to decorate

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a Class Decorator that takes a class where the first argument of the constructor is of defined type, and rest of arguments are free of choice.

When I add more arguments to the decorated class, I encounter the above error.

Trial 1: Setting other arguments of decorated class without a parameter property. This works, but then is forcing me to do: `this.property = property;` in the constructor.

Trial 2: Setting other arguments of decorated class as optional. But when tsconfig is set with `"strict": true` then every time I reference the property I need to use the ! `this!.property`.

```
export interface ServiceInstance<T> {
  children: Array<ServiceInstance<T>>;
}

export type ServiceConstructor<T> = new (children: Array<ServiceInstance<T>>, ...args: any) => ServiceInstance<T>;

export function ServiceDecorator<T>() {
  return function extendService(BaseService: ServiceConstructor<T>) {
    class ExtendedService extends BaseService {}
    return ExtendedService as ServiceConstructor<T>;
  };
}
```

What I would like to do is:

```js
@ServiceDecorator<string>()
class ServiceFoo {
  constructor(public children: Array<ServiceInstance<string>>, private bar: number) {}
}
```

This throws error: `Property 'bar' is missing in type 'ServiceInstance<string>' but required in type 'ServiceFoo'.ts(1238)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the type the decorator returns has to be compatible with the type you're decorating. You're returning a `ServiceConstructor<T>`, and while that's usually enough in this case, TypeScript has a hard time remembering the details around `T` (that might be a bug, but you can still work around it here). The first thing to change is that instead of using a type parameter `T` and saying you're returning a `ServiceConstructor<T>`, create a type parameter `Ctor extends ServiceConstructor<unknown>`.

The next things you'll notice is that `BaseService` can't be extended from because TypeScript only allows you to extend from specific patterns of generic function types. You'll need to simplify `ServiceConstructor`:

```
export type ServiceConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => ServiceInstance<T>;
```

Finally, you need to move the type parameter to the inner function, because in writing `@ServiceDecorator()`, you'll call `ServiceDecorator()` before actually decorating the class - but you need to have the class around to infer from.

Overall, your code should end up looking like this

```
export interface ServiceInstance<T> {
  children: Array<ServiceInstance<T>>;
}

export type ServiceConstructor<T> = new (
  ...args: any[]
) => ServiceInstance<T>;

export function ServiceDecorator() {
  return function extendService<Ctor extends ServiceConstructor<unknown>>(BaseService: Ctor) {
    let x = new BaseService([])
    class ExtendedService extends BaseService {}
    return ExtendedService;
  };
}

@ServiceDecorator()
class ServiceFoo {
  constructor(public children: Array<ServiceInstance<string>>, private bar: number) {}
}
```

Notice you don't need a type assertion in the inner functions anymore.

Comment: Thank you Daniel!
Is there a way to also force the class ServiceFoo to implement the interface ServiceInstance?